# How do I find an exact word in a string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check to see if the following string contains the word **"oil"**:

```
<script>
    var input = "Boil oil, soil toil, boiling toiling. Oils; oil: Oil. OIL! (oil)";

    // since there are 5 matches -- oil Oil OIL! oil: (oil), I would like this to output:
    var foundmatches = 5;
</script>
```

If the word is inside another word, I do not want it to count as a match.

The match can have a comma after it, a period, a semicolon, exclamation mark, a dash, or parenthesis. The text may be capital or lowercase.

Comment: Can you please add what you've tried on your own and why that did not work?

Comment: I am sure you can find a solution using regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `\boil\b` seems to work:

```js
var input = "Boil oil, soil toil, boiling toiling. Oils; Oil. OIL! (oil)";
var regex = /\boil\b/gi;
var found = input.match(regex);
console.log(found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/codegen?language=javascript)

It is exactly what you need.

```js
const regex = /\soil\s/gm;
const str = `Boil oil oil: soil toil Oil`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\Woil\W` regular expression with the *insensitive* flag enabled.

https://regex101.com/r/nLIwfs/2

Comment: Hey this is the only answer which seems to work. But what would the code be for Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to achieve kinda like that.

```
var yourString = "Boil oil, soil toil, boiling toiling. Oils; oil: Oil. OIL! (oil)"
var splittedOne = yourString.split(" ");

for(var i = 0; i < splittedOne.length; i++){ 
      if(splittedOne[i].toLowerCase().includes("oil")) { 
         console.log("contains ...")
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return you length of the amount of elements in the string.

```js
// Our input string
let input = "Boil oil, soil toil, boiling toiling. Oils; Oil. OIL!";

//Regex for word oil
var regex = /\boil\b/gi;

//print length of the array which contains all the words oil in a given input
console.log(input.match(regex).length)
```